How to prove the conclusion " linear operation $\mathsf{XOR}$ does not affect the division property"?
Division property is proposed as a generalized integral property at Eurocrypt 2015 by Yosuke Todo in his paper Structural evaluation by generalized integral property, And in paper Integral Cryptanalysis on Full MISTY1.
It says " linear operation $\mathsf{XOR}$ does not affect the division property", which means if every element in the input multiset is $\mathsf{XOR}$ed with a constant (or a key), the Division Property of the output multiset will be the same with the Division Property of the input multiset.
Could anyone please tell me if there is any proof for this conclusion?

The most important thing for you to do now, is to clarify if you've mis-typed "Diffusion" as "Division"; or if it's indeed "Division", what it means. I'm sure people would like to have this Q re-open and learn more about the paper you're looking at. I've restructured you prose, added link, and casted the 1st re-open vote.

I'm pretty sure I didn't mistype,  it is "Division", you can find it in Yosuke Todo's paper, or you can search "Division Property" in google scholar, you will find a lot of paper about it.

Let us first review the notations. For any $x, u \in \mathbb{F}_2^n$,
$$\pi_u(x) = \prod_{i=1}^n x[i]^{u[i]}$$
where $x[i]^1 = x[i]$ and $x[i]^0 = 1$. Equivalently, we can write
$$\pi_u(x) = \prod_{j\,s.t.\,u[j]=1} x[j]$$
The hamming weight of an element $x$ is denoted by $w_x$, i.e., $w_x = \sum_{i=1}^n x[i]$. Also, the set $S_k^n = \{x \in \mathbb{F}_2^n \,|\, w_x \geq k\}$ is the set of all elements with hamming weight greater than equal to $k$. Now, a multiset $\mathbb{X}$ has $D_{k}^n$ property if
$$\bigoplus_{x \in \mathbb{X}} \pi_u(x) = 0, \forall u \in (\mathbb{F}_2^n \setminus S_k^n)$$
i.e., the parity of $\pi_u(x)$ for all $x \in \mathbb{X}$ is even when $w_u < k$. Let us analyse the division property of the multiset $\mathbb{Y}$ obtained when the element $e_1 \in \mathbb{F}_2^n$ (the binary string with 1 in the first bit and 0 in the remaining) is $\mathsf{XOR}$ed to the multiset $\mathbb{X}$, i.e., $\mathbb{Y} = \{x \oplus e_1 \,|\, \forall x \in \mathbb{X}\}$. Let $u \in \mathbb{F}_2^n$ such that $1 \leq w_u <k$. Consider the case where $u[1] = 1$, then
$$\begin{align*} \bigoplus_{y \in \mathbb{Y}} \pi_u(y) &= \bigoplus_{x \in \mathbb{X}} \pi_u(x \oplus e_1)\\
&= \bigoplus_{x \in \mathbb{X}} \prod_{i=1}^n (x[i] \oplus e_1[i])^{u[i]} \\
&= \bigoplus_{x \in \mathbb{X}} \left( (x[1] \oplus 1)^{u[1]} \prod_{i=2}^n x[i]^{u[i]} \right) \\
&= \bigoplus_{x \in \mathbb{X}} \left( \prod_{i=1}^n x[i]^{u[i]} \oplus \prod_{i=2}^n x[i]^{u[i]} \right) \\
&= \left(\bigoplus_{x \in \mathbb{X}}  \prod_{i=1}^n x[i]^{u[i]} \right) \oplus \left( \bigoplus_{x \in \mathbb{X}} \prod_{i=2}^n x[i]^{u[i]} \right) \\
&= \left( \bigoplus_{x \in \mathbb{X}} \pi_u(x) \right) \oplus \left( \bigoplus_{x \in \mathbb{X}} \pi_{\tilde{u}}(x) \right)
\end{align*}$$
where $\tilde{u}[1] = 0$ and $\tilde{u}[i] = u[i], \forall 1 < i \leq n$. In other words, the hamming weight of $\tilde{u}$ is less than the hamming weight of $u$, i.e., $w_{\tilde{u}} < w_{u} < k$. Since $\mathbb{X}$ possesses $D_k^n$ property, both $\bigoplus_{x \in \mathbb{X}} \pi_u(x)$ and $\bigoplus_{x \in \mathbb{X}} \pi_{\tilde{u}}(x)$ are equal to 0.
Now, in the case of $u[1] = 0$, we will have
$$\bigoplus_{y \in \mathbb{Y}} \pi_u(y) = \bigoplus_{x \in \mathbb{X}} \pi_u(x \oplus e_1) = \bigoplus_{x \in \mathbb{X}} \pi_u(x) = 0$$
Repeating this process, we can show that the division property does not change when $\mathbb{X}$ is $\mathsf{XOR}$ed with any constant $a \in \mathbb{F}_2^{n}$ by decomposing $$a = \underset{j\,s.t.\,a[j]=1}{\oplus} e_j$$

@L0ngx1ng Thanks for pointing out the error in my proof. I have updated it.
